# DNX Core CLR: Symbols not loaded with CoreCLR (Debug / Attach To IIS Process)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

My goal is to
Debug with Visual Studio's Attach to Process functionality on the local IIS.

It works only when I use the **full framework** (dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7), but **not with the Core CLR** (dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7).

**When I choose the CoreCLR I cannot make any breakpoint, since it says that the symbols are not loaded.**

This is my publish.xml:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
  [...]
    <CompileSource>True</CompileSource>
    <PublishDNXVersion>dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7</PublishDNXVersion>
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
    <WebRoot>wwwroot</WebRoot>
    <WwwRootOut>wwwroot</WwwRootOut>
    <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
   [...]
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

- Just created a simple test project from the template (only with
  values controller).
- I would like to make my next project completely .NET Core based.
- That is why I want to make sure everything is working with .NET Core.
- I have the full source code of my example.
- I am using Visual Studio 2015

With the full CLR it works:
[image: Full CLR]

With the core CLR it does not work:
[image: Core CLR]

Comment: Do you have the symbols?

Comment: It is just a small test project which I created with the latest beta 7 mvc template inside visual studio 2015.